# Why does adding buttons to grid view causes text-view to change?

Tags: java, android

My android activity workout view displays a grid view. Each object of grid view either displays the name of an exercise and two buttons or it displays a exercise set and two buttons.This is what it looks like when I don't add buttons to each set.
[image]

Once I enable buttons to each set by commenting out `deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);` the activity displays this. changing the 3rd to last object to display an exercise instead of a set. (Scrolled down)
[image]

`getLocation(int i)` determines if an grid object is going to be an Exercise or set. location[0] determines the exercise and location[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXF7Y.png) if == 0 refers to exercise and location[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXF7Y.png) > 0 refers to an exercise set.

```
private int[] getLocation(int i) {
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    int temp[] = {-1, -1};

    int count = -1;
    for (int we = 0; we < WE_TABLE.size(); we++) {
        for (int s = 0; s < db.getSetCountByWEID(WE_TABLE.get(we).getID()) + 1; s++) {
            count++;

            if (count == i) {
                //Log.e("Test","WE: " + we+ " S: " + s + " For: " + i);
                temp[0] = we;
                temp[1] = s;
                db.closeDB();
                return temp;
            }

        }
    }
    db.closeDB();
    return temp;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int temp_p = position;
    TextView tv;
    View view = convertView;


    if (view == null) {
        totalObj++;
        Obj = totalObj;
        int[] location = getLocation(Obj - 1);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_workout_view_gridview, null);
        tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Button deleteBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
        Button addBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);


        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        String Exercises = (Obj + " " + location[0] + "," + location[1]);
        Log.e("Test", "Location: " + location[0] + " , " + location[1] + " Number " + Obj);


        if (location[1] == -1) {

        } else if (location[1] == 0) {
            WorkoutExercise WE = WE_TABLE.get(location[0]);
            Exercises = WE.getExerciseName();

            // addBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            S_TABLE = db.getSets(WE_TABLE.get(location[0]).getID() + "");
            Exercises = S_TABLE.get(location[1] - 1).getWeight() + "lbs " + S_TABLE.get(location[1] - 1).getReps() + " Reps";

            addBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something

            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do something

            }
        });
        tv.setText(Exercises);

        db.closeDB();

    }
    return view;


}
```

And My XML for each row is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="Dele" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:text="Add" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Look like you attached same picture twice.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that I accidentally hit submit before i finished typing.

Comment: It is layout problem. You buttons height more then text height, but they should be in same row.

Comment: What would i do to change that I added my XML too.

Comment: Have no idea. never work with android :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lowered the height to match the text and It is working properly, thanks to talex